# how do i make an li element go up right when reaching the bottom of a div element?

Tags: html, css, list, overflow

i have a list inside a div with fixed height, how can i make an li element overflowing go up right the others li elements?

i already tried using float: next but i want them to go from top to bottom then go right and top to bottom until i end my li elements.

i want to use only one list and not multiple lists next to each other.

that's my code right now,

```css
.test {
    height: 150px;
    width: 950px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                
            </ol>
        </div>
    <body>
<html>
```

explain me what should i do.

Comment: Is it an option to create multiple divs side to side and placing 8 li elements in each?

Comment: i do not quite understand what you want to do? do you want them all next to each other like a nav bar? or the height to be responsive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do this way:

```
.test {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/otfzgg52/

More documentation:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp